# React native - Link PushNotificatonsIOS manually

Tags: react-native

I want to lik the PushNotificationsIOS library manually. I used react-native link command but it only linked for android and it is working well on the android emulator. While I don’t have XCode I don’t know how to link it for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the doc guiding you to link `PushNotificationsIOS` manually.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html